# How can I use JXTable with JXSearchPanel for searching?

Tags: search, jtable, swingx, jxtable

I've read that the JXTable has a built-in support to search the table in combination 
with JXSearchPanel or JXSearchField. Wehre can I find some examples or code snippets 
to see how it works?

By the way: is there any possibility to disable the visibility of Combobox and checkbox 
in the JXSearchPanel?

many Thanks!